# What does it mean "But Jesus did not commit himself unto them, because he knew all men"?

Tags: john

In John 2: 23-25, Jesus does not commit himself unto the people so I am wondering how "many believed in his name, when they saw the miracles which he did." If he did not commit himself to them (which I am thinking means that He did not 'reveal' Himself fully to them?).

So my question really is, what did they believe of Him or does it mean something else when it says that He didn't commit Himself to men?